# Why Superfetch and Prefetch on Windows 8.1 cause high disk activity on Pagefile disk?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, superfetch, prefetch

I have an SSD running Windows 8.1 Pro x64, which only has 128GB.

To leave it a little more free, I have left only 200MB of Pagefile in it.

I have another HDD which has 1TB.
In it, I made a new partition (mounted on P:) with 10GB.

I've successfully set Windows to use that partition to store a 10GB Pagefile (less a few MB).

While I was playing, I noticed the high activity on that HDD.
It would freeze in certain areas and if I left it stopped for 5 minutes, and then moved a little, the HDD would go CRAZY!!!

I have detected the problem and it was Prefetch and Superfetch.
Disabling both resolved the issue.
To help on easing a little, I have disabled indexing in both the SSD and the HDD and reduced the size of the Pagefile to 6GB.

My question is: Why having Superfetch and Prefetch enabled caused such a huge use of the disk?
Shouldn't all the prefetched stuff be put in RAM?

Comment: If you have an SSD, why not disable the superfetch and prefetch?  This is easily done.

Comment: @mdpc I have. A long time ago (yesterday). My doubt is why Superfetch and Prefetch cause such high activity on the HDD with the Pagefile.

Comment: Insufficient memory causing swapping?

Comment: @mdpc Thats impossible. I had 2GB free **before** disabling Superfetch and Prefetch. Yes, the memory usage increased after disabling but that's normal and I don't mind it. I used to have always around 1.5-2GB of used memory and now it goes up 'till 3.75GB.